# Joomla: Passing Parameters from an Article to Module

Tags: module, joomla, joomla1.5

I am new to Joomla. I am developing a dynamic module which will display data relevant to the article with which the module is being displayed. Is it possible? If yes, how? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What parameters exactly are you talking about? I think all parameters could be gotten using article ID. And article ID always could be retieved from GET. You could use code like this:

```
if(JRequest::getVar('option')=='com_content' && JRequest::getVar('view')=='article')
{
    $article_id=JRequest::getVar('id');
    // then operate with ID.
}
```

If I'm wrong please specify your needs.

I hope it will be helpfull.

Comment: I have two questions: 1) I am using SEF URLs. Can I still get the article ID using above method? 2) Can I have a hidden text box in the article and read the value of that text box from the module?

Comment: 1) Yes. Article ID is always could be retrieved as GET-parameter. 2) Article isn't a form. It cannot have text box. What text box do you mean? Could you tell me what exactly are you going to do? I'll try to help you.

Comment: Basically, I need to display different products and its description. Each product will have separate page i.e separate article. Now I need a rating module to display the user ratings for the product. I have a table at backend which has corresponding ratings for the products. I thought of having a hidden textbox in my article by using PHP code. If you have any idea to achieve this, plz help me...

Comment: You could get article ID from GET in the module, then you could get product rating from the database according to the gotten ID. It is pretty easy

Comment: I will try that and keep you posted.